# Gradle : Can we override include statement in settings.gradle from command line arguments?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, multi-module

My `settings.gradle` has an include statement like below:

```
include 'sub-module-1', 'sub-module-2', 'sub-module-3'
```

Can i read the values of sub-modules which i want to include from command line arguments?

Answer (score 0):

Pass submodules list as a system property:

settings.gradle:

```
if (System.getProperties().submodules != null) {
    include System.getProperties().submodules.split(',')
}
```

command line:

```
./gradlew build -Dsubmodules=sub-module-1,sub-module-2,sub-module-3
```

Note that You cannot use project property instead, because `settings.gradle` is executed before project object is created.

Remember to handle case when `submodules` property isn't provided - You can raise an exception or set up some default submodules set.